# fetching geo data and timestamp from an image on iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there any way to tell the geo lat,long of an image taken in the camera on iphone, using the iphone sdk?

Is there any way to get the timestamp?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the images embedded EXIF data: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format

You can parse this data using: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/